# How to display data between range date

Tags: mysql

I have the following data:

```
entry   storenum    busidate    daily_budget
1       1           2017-07-01  4000
2       1           2017-07-02  1000
3       1           2017-07-03  6000
4       1           2017-07-04  7000
5       1           2017-07-05  12000
```

I need to display all the data between the range of the date(s).

I have tried to display all the data between the range date(s). Here is my current query:

```
SELECT
(CASE WHEN a.busidate BETWEEN '2017-07-01' AND '2017-07-05' THEN a.daily_budget ELSE 0 END) as Ideal,
b.store_name, b.storenum
FROM dummy_daily a JOIN site_store b ON b.storenum=a.storenum
WHERE b.storenum='1'
GROUP BY a.storenum
```

The above query only gives me the result of `2017-07-01`, not the data between `2017-07-01` and `2017-07-05`. Here is the example of result of my query:

```
Ideal       store_name          storenum
4000        Sunway Putra Mall   1
```

I need to display all the data between the date range.

Comment: Update your Query, Set `GROUP BY a.busidate` And Use `DATE RANGE` conditions in `WHERE` Clause.

Comment: :P I thought its something to do with date range too but I realize his using date range to determine how much daily_budget allocated.. the only issue is actually "GROUP BY"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Sumon Sarker As your Sugggestion. Your suggestion is perfectly correct
Here is the answer to display all rows between the date(s)

```
SELECT
a.daily_budget as Ideal,
b.store_name, b.storenum
FROM dummy_daily a JOIN site_store b ON b.storenum=a.storenum
WHERE b.storenum='1' and a.busidate BETWEEN '2017-07-01' AND '2017-07-05'
GROUP BY a.busidate
```

Answer (score 0):

the culprit might be the "GROUP BY"

try below query

```
 SELECT
    b.storenum,
    b.store_name,
    (CASE 
       WHEN a.busidate BETWEEN '2017-07-01' AND '2017-07-05' 
       THEN a.daily_budget ELSE 0 END
    ) AS Ideal 
  FROM dummy_daily a JOIN site_store b ON b.storenum=a.storenum
  WHERE b.storenum=1
  GROUP BY b.storenum,b.store_name, Ideal
```